# Multiple iterations in Progress Bar C# WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, progress-bar, backgroundworker

I have two classes - form and functions. Function class consists of, unexpectedly, functions, and there are many of them (let's say 20). They all use different algorithms and external libraries, but they all pass progress indexes in cycles to show the progress. I need to pass these indexes in progress bar in my form. I'm inclined to use Background Worker, but probably I'm mistaken. The problem is that I don't know how many functions the user will choose, so I can't put these algorithms in DoWork event handler or transferring them to any other class, they should remain the same.

I simplified the code and left only 2 functions:

```
class Functions
    {

        public void First()
        {
            int progressIndex = 0;
            // declaring something, e.g.
            int size = 420;
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                // some operations, finally:
                progressIndex++;

                form.label1.Text = "Function 1 executing..."; // also, how do I pass this to the label?
            }

            return;
        }

        // similar
        public void Second()
        {
            int index = 0;
            int gridCount = 86039;
            for (int i = 0; i < gridCount; i++)
            {
                index++;

                form.label1.Text = "Function 2 executing...";

            return;
        }
    }
```

Form:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Functions functions;
        
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void buttonStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Execute();
            label1.Visible = true;
            label2.Visible = true;
            buttonStop.Visible = true;
            buttonStart.Enabled = false;
        }

        void Execute()
        {
            if (isFirst)
                functions.First();

            if (isSecond)
                functions.Second();
        }

        private void buttonStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            worker.CancelAsync();
        }

        private void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {   
            // ???
        }

        private void worker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
            label2.Text = (e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() + "%");
        }

        private void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Cancelled == true)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Cancelled");
            }
            else if (e.Error != null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error: " + e.Error.Message);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Completed!");
            }
        }

        public bool isFirst
        {
            get { return checkBox1.Checked; }
            set { checkBox1.Checked = value; }
        }

        public bool isSecond
        {
            get { return checkBox2.Checked; }
            set { checkBox2.Checked = value; }
        }
```

Will appreciate any help, thank you

I need my progress bar to show the progress one after another, for example if user choosed 3 functions out of 20, it will show 3 full iterations from 0 to 100.

Comment: Have you heard of [IProgress<T>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iprogress-1?view=net-8.0) before? Also, if you have (possibly) long(ish)-running Algorithms, you'd not want them to block your EventHandlers but run on the thread pool, which will lead you to async/Task sooner or later.

Answer (score 1):

To report progress you should pass a reference to your counter as an argument. This allow the UI and functions to share the same counter, while still keeping them separate. It also allow the function to be called with a dummy counter that is not connected to anything.

The typical way to do this would be to use the [Progress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.progress-1?view=net-8.0) class. My preference is to use a double in the range 0 to 1 as the argument, so the caller does not need to know the actual number of iterations. The `Progress<T>` will raise its `ProgressChanged` event on the UI thread, so should be fairly straightforward to use.

```
public void First(IProgress<double> progress)
{
    // declaring something, e.g.
    int size = 420;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        progress.Report( i / (double)size);
        ...        
    }

    return;
}
```

In most cases you would run your function using Task.Run: `Task.Run(() => First(progress))`. Ideally functions should be "Pure" to avoid threading issues, i.e. compute a value from the parameters, and have no side effects. Side effects like  reporting progress, cancelling and logging can sometimes be ignored when making this determination.